# Discord.py song queuing system

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, youtube-dl

I am trying to code a discord music bot and it worked until i converted the queuing system from a list of URLs to a dictionary with the song name so i can display what's playing next.

When the second song is about to play I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\sammy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py:611: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
  self.after(error)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Here is the code, I've trimmed it a bit so that it's not super long:

```
global ydl_opts
ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }


from discord.utils import get
global voice
global queue_list
queue_list = {}

def queue():
    global queue_list
    print("hi")
    print(len(queue_list))
    if len(queue_list) != 0:
        keys = list(queue_list.keys())
        values = list(queue_list.values())
        print("AAAAAAAAAAAAA: " + str(values[0]))
        play_url(str(values[0]))
        print("AAAAAAAAAAAAA2: " + str(queue_list[keys[0]]))

        del queue_list[keys[0]]

        print(str(queue_list))

def play_url(url):
    try:
        os.remove("song.mp3")
    except:pass

    url = str(url)
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: queue())
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.07

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, curl):
    #global voice
    try:
        global voice
        voice = await ctx.message.author.voice.channel.connect()
    except:pass
    if voice.is_playing() == False:
        print("first")
        song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
        try:
            if song_there:
                os.remove("song.mp3")
        except PermissionError:
            return

        #voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        play_url(curl)
    elif voice and voice.is_playing():
        print("next")
        info_dict = YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).extract_info(curl, download=False)#youtube dl attribute settings are needed
        #print(info_dict['title'])
        if info_dict.get('title', None) in queue_list:
            queue_list[str(info_dict['title']) + str(random.randint())] = curl
        else:
            queue_list[str(info_dict['title'])] = curl
        #print(str(queue_list))
        pass

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def pause(ctx):
    #voice = get(ctx.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    #voice = await ctx.message.author.voice.channel.connect()
    if voice and voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def resume(ctx):
    if voice and voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume()

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def stop(ctx):
    global queue_list
    queue_list = []
    if voice and voice.is_playing():
        voice.stop()

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def skip(ctx):
    voice.stop()
    try:
        os.remove("song.mp3")
    except:pass
    play_url(queue_list[0])

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def queue(ctx):
    values = list(queue_list.values())
    keys = list(queue_list.keys())
    await ctx.send("*Up Next:*")
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        info_dict = YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).extract_info(values[i], download=False)

        message = "**" + str(i + 1) + ".** " + str(keys[i]) + " (" + str(info_dict['duration']) + ")"
        await ctx.send(message)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C:\Users\sammy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py:611: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.**call**' was never awaited
> self.after(error)
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

As your error code states you forgot to add "await" at the beginning of line 611.

**C:\Users\sammy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py** is the file path for your script

**:611:** is the line within aforementioned file

**RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.**call**' was never awaited self.after(error)** is what went wrong within the file.

I hope this breakdown has been helpful for you and aids your ventures.

Comment: Hello @St0rmWalker, not sure this is helping. _player.py_ is a file from Discord python package [1]. You can improve your answer by highlighting in the question the line that triggers the error. It is likely that it is the callback passed in the after param: `voice.play(..., after=lambda e: queue())` 
[1] https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/7836046621d6b670730217ad4de321ef3ecd5cff/discord/player.py

Answer (score 0):

(Usually) means you forgot to use `await` before a coroutine (functions starting with `async`) somewhere, which is mandatory.